# how to slip this multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a nested array and I wanted to know if there is a way to slip it, so having the nested arrays as individual arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [pizza] => Array
                        (
                            [Tomato & Cheese] => Array
                                (
                                    [small] => 5.50
                                    [large] => 9.75
                                )

                            [Olives] => Array
                                (
                                    [small] => 6.85
                                    [large] => 10.85
                                )

                        )

                    [Speciality Pizzas] => Array
                        (
                            [Our Special] => Array
                                (
                                    [ingredients] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Tomatoes
                                            [1] => Olives
                                            [2] => Spinach
                                            [3] => Fresh Garlic
                                            [4] => Mozzarella & Feta Cheese
                                        )  --- theres more but you get the idea
```

Now I want to may a new array with all the pizzas, but without knowing the name "pizza"

at the moment I can do this:

```
$array = array(json_decode($json, true));
$pizzas = (array)$array[0]['menu']['pizza']
```

But if the menu changes content (but not structure) and if the 'pizza' changes to 'salads' the above would fail.  Is the a way to create the above pizzas array without the name

Thanks

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. For instance, what do you want to do with the `Speciality Pizzas` array (or any other arrays at the same level as `pizza` or `salads`? And how are you gonna process those results later on? Do you want, what is now called `$pizza` to be renamed as well? And how will you be able to access it later on then?

Comment: I want to slit them so I have an array for pizzas, one for salads, and so on. but I wanted a way to do that without using the words 'pizza', 'salad' ....

Comment: I understand this, but how do you want to access the result(s) later on? What will be the name of the resulting variable(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(json_decode($json, true));
$menu = (array)$array[0]['menu'];
foreach($menu as $item => $item_Data){
    //$item might be pizza for example
    //$item_Data might be Olives or Our special. Now you have to consider what to do with this. Maybe next foreach loop ?
}
```

Comment: hi @geneses - when I echo $item_Data it shows only "array", I understand why, then I did another foreach loop where $item_data as $something. that works, but it echos all the pizzas AND all the Speciality Pizzas - where as I wanted the loop to stop in the last pizza

Answer (score 0):

Right now your array has parallel sections for related data. How about if you did something like:

```
$food_choices = array(
     'pizza' => array(
         'Tomato & Cheese' => array(
               'type' => 'regular',
               'prices' => array(...),
               'ingredients' => array(...)
         ),
         'Our Special' => array(
              'type' => 'specialty',
              'prices' => array(...),
              'ingredients' => array(...)
         ),
     ),
     'salads' => array(
          'Caesar' => array(...);
          'Tossed' => array(...);
     )
)
```

where all the information related to any one menu item as all in the same branch of the meu tree. Then to access any one pizza's information is as simple as:

```
$data = $food_choices['pizza']['Tomato & Cheese'];
echo 'The large of this pizza costs $', $data['prices']['large'];
echo 'The small Caesar salad contains ', implode($food_choices['salad']['Caesar']['ingredients);
```

Comment: yes but the $data = $food_choices['pizza']['Tomato & Cheese'];
is not the way I wanted it. is there a way to do that without knowing the values for example $data = $food_choices[$anything][$anything]; as if after I implement this, the restorant wants to change these heading, the code you provide (though great) would fail if pizza changes to 'great pizzas'

Answer (score 0):

A series of foreach loops might do, even though I don't know what you're doing.

```
<?php

    $pizza = '';

    foreach ($array as $food) {

        $pizza .= $food;

        if (is_array($food)) {

            foreach ($food as $option) {

                $pizza .= " > " . $option;

                if (is_array($option)) {

                    foreach ($option as $value) {

                        //etc
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To learn about the keys in an array, use the [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) function ([Demo](http://codepad.org/hfyJwQXr)):

```
$array = array(array('menu' => array(/* ... */))); # your array

print_r(array_keys($array[0])); # Array(menu)
```